# How do i extract saved numpy array from my Azure DataStore?

Tags: python, azure, dataset, datastore, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a numpy array which is saved in my azure datastore. I have all the necessary credentials. However, when it comes to extracting numpy arrays, Azure has not provided any methods for their retrieval. I have tried this code but it is unable to reach the correct location.

If i go to the correct location, the data is shown stored in an https format which doesnt make sense. Please advise

```
path=str(self.datastore)+str(self.train_data_outputs_folder) + '/' + 'w2v_emb'+ '_' + str(self.date_range) + '.npy'
        print("The new path is:",path)
        ds=np.DataSource()
        # f=ds.open(path=(self.datastore,
        #           self.train_data_outputs_folder + '/' + 'w2v_emb'+ '_' + self.date_range + '.npy'))
        f=ds.open(path)
        dat=np.fromfile(f)
```

Comment: How are you loading the file (i.e.. uploading or saving directly from Notebook) and What type of data do you have in your path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a numpy array from_files method of dataset similar to shown below

```
 def file_download(path):
            dataset = Dataset.File.from_files(path=(self.datastore,self.train_data_outputs_folder+"/"+ path))
            datafolder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'numpy_file')
            dataset.download(datafolder, overwrite=True)
```

the essence is that you got to download the files to your local repo. you can use that using the download method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).